# libcurl with android source build

Tags: android, libcurl

I need to build the libcurl for using android ndk-build , as tried the steps provided in the link 
 [porting libcurl on android with ssl support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330180/porting-libcurl-on-android-with-ssl-support)

Here they suggested to compile the source code of the androidi as given in the first step .
is it necessary to compile the android source code or just compiling the curl code is sufficient ? if so pls give the proper link ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "build all" approach is described in the [Android.mk](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/Android.mk) file in the curl distribution. The other methods are described in the [docs/INSTALL](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/docs/INSTALL#L847) file from the same place.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled just the code, the one I got from here:https://github.com/gcesarmza/curl-android-ios   then I installed NDK to eclipse and added NDK support to the project.