# CURL Library for Android

Tags: android, curl, file-upload, android-ndk, libcurl

After much struggling, I managed to setup this Android NDK project on eclipse:

```
https://github.com/gcesarmza/curl-android-ios
```

...and now it runs. All it does is connect to www.google.com:
This is the curl call I make in the Main Activity:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com";
byte[] content = downloadUrl(url);
```

I am new to NDK an this CURL library, how can I execute a more complex CURL request such as this file upload command??? :

```
curl -F file=@audio.wav http://myserver.com
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4952169/4596556 and http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.in/2010/05/porting-of-libcurl-to-android-os-using.html

Comment: Hi @MadhukarHebbar , I had already checked both links, but they talk more about setting up the library, dont tell how to do a request such as: curl -F file=@audio.wav http://myserver.com  (might be I am still too green on this, sorry)

Comment: `String url = "http://myserver.com/audio.wav";` And you forgot to tell what exactly your curl request does.

Answer (score 0):

The test project that you reproduced does only this, downloadUrl.

If you want something else, you need to write (in C or C++) your own code that uses libCURL. You can start with a [generic tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html).

You will also need to define some JNI wrapper, e.g.

```
native bool pushFile(String file)
```

Alternatively, you can use an [existing JNI wrapper](https://github.com/aloha-app/libcurldroid).